# Need to add a column in main query from a table from which i am using another column to filter data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I Need to add a column pf_id in main query from a table ufs from which i am using another column site_id to filter data.

Following is the query:

```
SELECT
  time_key, ts,  
  if (uptime is null, 0, uptime) as uptime,
  if (availability is null, 0, round(availability, 2)) as availability
FROM (
  SELECT
    (86400 * DIV(timestamp, 86400)) AS time_key,
    MAX(timestamp) AS ts,
    ROUND(AVG(value),2) AS uptime
  FROM
    rc_positional_accuracy(1683657000, 168, 86400) // routine 
  WHERE
    timestamp > 0
    and site_id in (select distinct site_id from `ufs`)
  GROUP BY
    time_key ) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    (86400 * DIV(timestamp, 86400)) AS time_key,
    ((SUM( IF (available, 1, 0)) / COUNT( DISTINCT device_id)) / DIV (MAX(timestamp) - MIN(timestamp)+1800, 1800 ) ) * 100 AS availability,
  FROM
    rc_availability_hours(1683657000, 168, 1800) // routine
  WHERE
    timestamp > 0
  and site_id in (select distinct site_id from `ufs `)
  GROUP BY
    time_key ) c
USING
  (time_key)
```

The schema of ufs is
user_id      String
pf_id        String
site_id     String

rc_positional_accuracy : is returning > timestamp, timekey,   site_id,    zone_id,    device_id, errorCode, currentMode , currentAngle, calculatedAngle

rc_availability_hours : is returning > site_id, zone_id, device_id, timekey,currentMode,errorCode,timestamp, available

in the above query, apart from time_key, ts, uptime and availability in the main query i need to display the portfolio_id in each row for which the site_id belongs to.

e.g

```
pfid time_key   ts        uptime availability
A   1684195200  1684240130  96  100
B   1683590400  1683676682  100 100
B   1683590400  1683676682  100 100
A   1684195200  1684239884  100 91.89
C   1684195200  1684239884  100 91.89
D   1684022400  1684105747  100 97.19
A   1684022400  1684105747  100 97.19
E   1684022400  1684105747  100 97.19
B   1683849600  1683935509  100 100
```

Currently, executing the above query as is gives me the following output,

```
time_key    ts  uptime  availability
1683590400  1683676799  96.09   95.79
1683676800  1683763199  98.88   91.57
1683763200  1683849599  98.83   93.35
1683849600  1683935999  97.9    95.73
1683936000  1684022399  98.12   96.52
1684022400  1684108799  98.8    95.78
1684108800  1684195199  98.86   96.29
1684195200  1684240200  99.32   95.22
```

i have tried joining the data with ufs table by grouping the subqueries also with site_id along with time_key, and later matching the site_id. but that is not giving the correct output. reason is, my query should only perform the operations and group by using time_key filtered by a given set of site_ids for a particular pf_id. i don't want to group by pf_id. i just want to display the pf_id information in each for which the data belongs to